# why are properties in my response object set to null?

Tags: c#, json, post, .net-6.0, httpresponse

I have this endpoint method:

```
var authToken = await [url]
                    .AddAuthHeaders(config)
                    .PostJsonAsync(new AuthTokenRequest
                    {
                        GrantType = "test",
                        ClientId = "test",
                        ClientSecret = "test",
                        Audience = "test"
                    })
                    .ReceiveJson<AuthTokenResponse>();
```

It's calling this endpoint:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Get([FromBody] object request)
{
    try
    {
        var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
            {
                Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
                {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "test")
                }),
                Issuer = _issuer,
                Audience = _audience,
                SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(
                    new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_key)),
                    SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha512Signature)
            };

        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);

        // Create a new instance of the AuthTokenResponse class and set its properties
        var response = new AuthTokenResponse
            {
                AccessToken = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token).ToString(),
                TokenType = "Bearer",
                ExpiresSeconds = token.ValidTo.Subtract(token.ValidFrom).TotalSeconds.ToString(),
                AuthTokenType = AuthTokenType.Generic
            };

        return Ok(response);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError(ex, "Error generating token for request {Request}", request);
        return BadRequest();
    }
}
```

My `AuthTokenReponse` class is:

```
[DataContract]
public class AuthTokenResponse
{
    [DataMember(Name = "access_token")]
    public string AccessToken { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "token_type")]
    public string TokenType { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "expires_in")]
    public string ExpiresSeconds { get; set; }

    public AuthTokenType AuthTokenType { get; set; }
}

public enum AuthTokenType
{
    Generic,
    Custom
}
```

Now when I call the endpoint using the post method, it hits the end point as it should, and I can see the response object generate all the correct properties. It generates a token, which I can clearly see and returns a valid response object.

However, the application receiving the object, receives this:

```
                AccessToken null
                TokenType null
                ExpiresSeconds null
                AuthTokenType Generic
```

Everything is null, apart from `AuthTokenType`, which has the correct value.

when i use postman i get the correct values

```
{
    "accessToken": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1bmlxdWVfbmFtZSI6Indob2NhcmVzaXRzZmFrZSIsIm5iZiI6MTY4MzMxNDAxMiwiZXhwIjoxNjgzMzE3NjEyLCJpYXQiOjE2ODMzMTQwMTIsImlzcyI6Imh0dHBzOi8vbG9jYWxob3N0OjUwODg5LyIsImF1ZCI6Imh0dHBzOi8vbG9jYWxob3N0OjUwODg5LyJ9.W_qvEBeF4gGMYAKA6n09bYPWsKrWvpEwRc0b7DdZuNJf4RDU25yh3GUv5Ht0UupoBqGYHDBfBjR8O21sv-56rg",
    "tokenType": "Bearer",
    "expiresSeconds": "3600",
    "authTokenType": 0
}
```

I can't work out why this is? Is it that that the object is not serializing its properties? Any thoughts?

Comment: Your `Get` code appears not to use `request` at all, other than in the exception path. Surely that's not deliberate.

Comment: Correct, that was changed for the sake of this question

Comment: That really doesn't help, IMO. It doesn't help that we don't know much about the calling code, either, or how either the server or client are configured in terms of serialization. (Personally I haven't seen `DataMember` in a while - it's more common to see `JsonProperty` or `JsonPropertyName` in modern code.) Have you looked at the response being sent on the wire, or tried fetching it just as a string in the calling code? The first thing to work out is whether the problem is in the client or the server.

Comment: _"However, the application receiving the object, receives this:"_ - are you sure that it RECEIVES that and not deserializes to that? Have you checked the actual response content. Can you share the code of the app receiving the results?

Comment: It works via postman, but calling it from the client doesn't work, when using postman the properties are set, when being called from an application everything but authtokentype is null

Comment: Hey @GuruStron the first code chunk is the application calling the controller and the last code chunk is what it receives

Comment: It seems that you are using Flurl. Am I correct? Can you share JSON you get in postman?

Comment: hey @GuruStron i have updated the post with the postman result :)  and yes I am using flurl

Comment: Probably you are using Json.NET somewhere in your tool chain to deserialize `AuthTokenResponse` but not to serialize -- or vice versa.  And since Json.NET [supports data contract attributes](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DataContractAndDataMember.htm), on one end of the wire snake casing is used, but on the other end it is not.  Try removing the data contract attributes and see if the problem goes away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem seemed to be that

ReceiveJson expects a json serialised object,

I fixed this by serialising the object before sending

```
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response);

            return Ok(json);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be the data contract attributes. Assuming you are using the [default Flurl serializer](https://flurl.dev/docs/configuration/#serializers) - Newtonsoft's Json.NET which will honor the attributes ([see the docs](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DataContractAndDataMember.htm)). Either remove `DataMember` attributes or add `JsonProperty` ones (which will take precedence):

```cs
[DataContract]
public class AuthTokenResponse
{
    [DataMember(Name = "access_token")]
    [JsonProperty("accessToken")]
    public string AccessToken { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "token_type")]
    [JsonProperty("tokenType")]
    public string TokenType { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "expires_in")]
    [JsonProperty("expiresSeconds")]
    public string ExpiresSeconds { get; set; }

    public AuthTokenType AuthTokenType { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Would that explain why the enum was the only value being populated?

Comment: @dros maybe. `Generic` is the default value, so it can be populated due to this.

Comment: Would this have to be reflected on the clients response model aswell?

Comment: @dros do not fully understand the question.

Comment: the application receiving the authtokenresponse, also has the same  AuthTokenResponse model. would the change need to be reflected on the receiving model aswell?

Comment: @dros based on provided info in the question - change is required only on the receiving side.

Comment: i found out the problem, I will share the answer, thank you for your contributions